# I have a azure frontdoor with caching enabled on route by deafult the caching is 1 to 3 days how to override it using rules what condition to use

Tags: azure, caching, azure-front-door, azure-caching

I have a azure frontdoor with caching enabled on route by deafult the caching is 1 to 3 days how to override it using rules what condition to use so that it executes for all requests.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the results successfully like below.***

I have created an azure front door and enabled on route by default ***Enable caching*** like below:

[image]

To override your caching rule check the below:

In your azure front door -> under setting,-> Front door designer -> click on the routing rule like below:

[image]

While updating the routing rule by default it enables **`use default duration as yes`**

[image]

Click on your routing rule -> choose `use default duration as NO`** and you can change the duration of caching behavior like below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think this is valid for classic Azure Front Door but not for Azure standard or premium SKUs.